# Write and Get information from config.yml?

Tags: java, yaml, bukkit

So I'm creating my own plugin called HomeTown. And the plugin can display a custom "Help" section. But now I need to create a block of code that can:

1. Store the Player's name
2. Under Player name, the town that the Player belongs to.

And be able to get that information.

here is what I've got so far..

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    public FileConfiguration myConfigFile = null;
    public File MyFile;

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("Plugin has been invoked");

        File MyFile = new File("players.yml");
        if(!MyFile.exists()){
            try {
                MyFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        YamlConfiguration myConfigFile = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(MyFile);


    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getLogger().info("Plugin has been disabled!");
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("test")) {

            Player player = (Player) sender;
            YamlConfiguration MyFile = new YamlConfiguration();
            MyFile.createSection("test");

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } 
}
```

And I have a players.yml config file in my `.jar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store player's name and town's name, simply do:

```
myConfigFile.set(townname, playername);
```

But I suggest using player's UUID, istead of player's name, since in 1.8+ names will become changable!

```
myConfigFile.set(townname, player.getUniqueId());
```

Then to get the town's owner:

```
myConfigFile.getString(townname);
```

You will find better answers and informations on [Bukkit forums](https://forums.bukkit.org/)

Comment: When i change my MyFile.createSection("test"); to getConfig().set(player.getName(), "SomeKingdom"); it didn't write anything in the players.yml

Comment: nvm then about getConfig(), I thought your config file is config.yml

Comment: Can you please add me on skype: Olya___vitya